# Devise strong parameter sanitizer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, strong-parameters

I am trying to customize my input params when using devise.  To the best of my ability I have followed the [devise doc](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) on the subject.  I have also googled extensively finding some helpful articles like [this](http://blog.12spokes.com/web-design-development/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4/) one. In the end however what happens when I fill out the form and hit submit, is the "sign_up" form on the new user page is returned.  When I check the db in the console no new user is added and the server logs is listed below with the relevant code. If you'd like to see any other code let me know and Ill up date the question.  Any and all help is mush appreciated.

Server logs:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up
utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=lnKi02OIXc3sSkCpCzKmvQ6iaSZPI6s9aVxN9pCavH8%3D&user%5Bemail%5D=kit%40kit.com&user%5Bhandle%5D=kit&user%5Bpassword%5D=[FILTERED]&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=[FILTERED]&commit=Sign+Up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-17 21:01:31 -0800
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"lnKi02OIXc3sSkCpCzKmvQ6iaSZPI6s9aVxN9pCavH8=", "user"=>{"email"=>"kit@kit.com", "handle"=>"kit", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign Up"}
Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.3ms)
Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 9.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

My application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception


 protected

 def devise_parameter_sanitizer
    if resource_class == User
      User::ParameterSanitizer.new(User, :user, params)
    else
      super # Use the default one
    end
 end
end
```

User_sanitizer:

```
class User::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer

private
def account_sign_in
    default_paramiters.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :handle, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) 
end

def account_sign_up
    default_paramiters.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :handle, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) 
end

def account_account_update
    default_paramiters.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :handle, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) 
end
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Meowit</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<%= root_path %>">MeowIT</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="<%= meows_path %>">Feed</a></li>



    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>

        <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= "#{current_user.email}" %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to("Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
        <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to("Login  ", new_user_session_path) %></li>
        <% end %>

  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>

  <% if flash[:success] %>
    <div class='alert alert-success'>
      <%= flash[:success] %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if flash[:info] %>
    <div class='alert alert-info'>
      <%= flash[:info] %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if flash[:warning] %>
    <div class='alert alert-warning'>
      <%= flash[:warning] %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if flash[:danger] %>
    <div class='alert alert-danger'>
      <%= flash[:danger] %>
    </div>
  <% end %>


    <div class="container">

      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

sanitizers.rb:

```
require "#{Rails.application.root}/lib/user_sanitizer.rb"
```

new.html.erb (inside views/devise/registrations):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="well">
      <form class="bs-example form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Sign Up</legend>
        <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <%= f.error_notification %>


              <%= f.label :Email, class: "col-lg-2 control-label" %>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <%= f.text_field :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
              </div>

                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <br>

              <%= f.label :"Name", class: "col-lg-2 control-label" %>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <%= f.text_field :handle, :required => false, class: "form-control" %>
              </div>


                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <br>

              <%= f.label :Password, class: "col-lg-2 control-label" %>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <%= f.password_field :password, :required => true, class: "form-control" %>
              </div>


                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <br>

              <%= f.label :"Password Confirmation", class: "col-lg-2 control-label" %>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :required => true, class: "form-control" %>
              </div>

                  <br>
                  <br>

              <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <%= f.button :submit, "Sign Up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
              </div>

        <% end %>


        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

**edit(1)**

Created new file 
registrations_controller.rb in app/controllers
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

```
      private

        def configure_devise_params
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
            u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
          end
        end
    end
```

Modified the devies_for route in routes.rb to point to the new controller.

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Last, I commented out the reference to the devise_parameter_sanitizer in the application controller and removed the

```
    require "#{Rails.application.root}/lib/user_sanitizer.rb"
```

in sanitizers.rb

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need the help, but I was able to get my sanitizers working by dropping the prefixed accounts.

Inside you user_sanitizer.rb remove "accounts" from your methods.

```
def sign_in
    ...
end  

def sign_up
    ...
end
```

Doing it this way has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to devise registrations controller

```
private

def configure_devise_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
    u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Comment: I was trying to do essentially the same thing in the user_sanitizer.rb, requiring it  thru the sanitizers.rb. With the same result and no `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes` I think I'm missing something else. Please refer to edit(1) in the question see how I implemented the above.